# Determine whether a date falls on weekend in Angular/Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, momentjs, weekend

Given a date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, how can I determine whether a date falls in the weekend in Angular/Javascript?

```
$scope.isWeekend= function(){ 
  $scope.date = '2018-05-13'; 
  /* if (day(date)=='saturday' || day(date)=='sunday') { */
  alert("");
  /* } */
}
```

Comment: `$scope.date = 2018-05-13` ... so, date is `2000`? what does that mean? which calendar system is that?

Comment: 30 seconds google search ... https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using momentjs just for determining whether a date falls on a weekend is a bit overkill.

You can do it reliably in vanilla JavaScript in just four easy steps :

1. Split your `yyyy-mm-dd` into a `[yyyy, mm, dd]` array.
2. Use [`new Date(year, month, day)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to create a `Date` object, using the values in your array.
   Note that for `month` a value between 0 and 11 rather than between 1 and 12 is expected.
3. Use [`date.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) to get a numeric representation of the day of the week, where 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, 2 is Tuesday, etc.
4. Check whether the the day of the week is 0 or 6.

---

#### Demo

```js
function isWeekend(dateString) {
  /* Step 1 */ var dateArray = dateString.split("-");
  /* Step 2 */ var date = new Date(dateArray[0], dateArray[1] - 1, dateArray[2]);
  /* Step 3 */ var day = date.getDay();
  /* Step 4 */ return day === 0 || day === 6;
}

console.log(isWeekend("2018-05-03")) // false
console.log(isWeekend("2018-05-04")) // false
console.log(isWeekend("2018-05-05")) // true
console.log(isWeekend("2018-05-06")) // true
console.log(isWeekend("2018-05-07")) // false
console.log(isWeekend("2018-05-08")) // false
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! Appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Date#getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) to get day of week and check if it is 6 (Saturday) or 0 (Sunday):

```js
function isWeekend(string) {
  var date = new Date(string);
  return date.getDay() === 6 || date.getDay() === 0;
}

console.log(isWeekend('2018-05-13'));
console.log(isWeekend('2018-05-12'));
console.log(isWeekend('2018-03-13'));
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried but somehow in my browser console, it keeps output other date after running the new Date(string)  line.

Comment: @user21 -- Oh! I completely missed out that you can use MomentJS. I didn't see the post is tagged. But I see you accepted mahan's answer which already does that. So I will keep my answer as it is. :)

Answer (score 1):

In `momentjs`, use  `moment('YYYY-MM-DD').day()` to get the number of the day and then check if it equals `6` or `0`(Saturday or Sunday).

```js
function isWeekend(date) {
  var date = moment(date),day = date.day();
  return (day === 6) || (day === 0)
}

console.log(isWeekend("2018-05-06")) // true
console.log(isWeekend("2018-05-08")) // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```